# How to Change Django AbstractUser Group to String

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I made some groups inside of Django Admin, but whenever I add a user to one of those groups, only the group ID displays inside of my API endpoint. Is there a way to display the string name?

[image: Adding Myself to Directors]

[image: It Shows up as 1 in the endpoint]

So instead of 1, I want the field to be "Directors". Does it have anything to do with extending the AbstractUser Model?

This is all I have right now, for my User info:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
```

Serializer.py

```
from .models import User
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ["username", "password"]
        model = User
```

Comment: Can you share your serializer?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yep, I updated it, it's pretty bare bones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`SlugRelatedField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to serialize the groups:

```
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # serialize groups with "slugs" ↓
    groups = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        slug_field='name'
     )

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['username', 'password']
        model = User
```